# TextArea affect on click enter AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can you do so that the textarea adds what is typed after the enter?

```
   <div style="display: none;" id="id_warstwy2{{$index}}">
        <form ng-submit="addTask(newTask, $index)">
           <textarea ng-model="newTask"   rows="3"></textarea>
        </form>
       <button style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Add</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: after the enter means?? please elaborate your problem properly...

Comment: I want to after click enter on keyboard was called function addTask, because at this moment is that when u click enter is next br inside textarea not not called function

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive like this:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function(e) {
            if(e.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {'e': e});
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            }
         });
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea ng-model="newTask" ng-enter="addTask(newTask, $index)"  rows="3"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-keypress` something like

```
<textarea ng-model="newTask" ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)? 
addTask(newTask, $index) : return"></textarea>
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qc35zcm5/)

Comment: what is better option ? :D ur or in with directiv??

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska ng-keypress is an inbuilt directive of angular then why use coustom directive?

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska you can mark  it as answer if this works for you

Comment: Directives can be reused multiple times. This way, if you are going to use the functionality in several sites, you do not need to evaluate in your html the $event. Your code will become clearer with `ng-enter = "addTask(newTask, $index)"` than with `ng-keypress = "($ event.charCode == 13)? addTask (newTask, $index): return "`

Comment: @Naimad do you know ng-keypress is also an directive?

Comment: Yes I know. but I think my code is much cleaner with a custom directive.

Comment: @Naimad ok bro as you thought i don't wanna argue on this

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about on how to trigger ng-submit using enter ??? 
if it is just put your button inside form then put `type="submit"`

```
    <form ng-submit="addTask(newTask, $index)">
       <textarea ng-model="newTask"   rows="3"></textarea>
       <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Add</button>
    </form>
```